# Navigation controller do not respond correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my project I have a view embed in a `navigationController` and a detail view which is pushed by a button.

It works perfectly as usual, but here I have a couple of issues :

**1. All the stack in the navigation controller do not appear**

[image]

**2. I manually had a segue inside the next button in the storyboard but I have this message in the console:**

[image]

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is
>   managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

**Below my `ViewController` code :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: - Properties


    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var titleNavigationBar: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }

    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    // MARK: - Internal methods




    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: is your NavigationController initial view controller?

Comment: No, but this required in my project.

Comment: set UINavigationController isInitialViewController from storyboard

Comment: This is done but the stack of the navigation controller still do not appear.

Comment: I read your post twice but couldn't get what's your exact problem, please clarify 1) Expected result 2) What you get currently

Comment: Do you want to navigate to Next screen on Next button tap event?

Comment: 1/I want the navigation controller title and bar button item appear and also the next button push a detail view controller.
2/ Navigation controller is not displayed and I have error when I pressed Next Button

Comment: @PPL, yes this is what I want.

Comment: You can easily drag and assign segue to next controller and select show

Comment: I've also done it

Comment: It must work then, there is some other error from your end, please cross verify it

Comment: Have you hidden navigation controller any where in the app?

Comment: You can take a screenshot on an iOS device by pressing the Top or Side button and the Home button simultaneously. (On iPhone X, it's Volume Up + the Side button). [Read more about taking screenshots here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289)

Comment: @the4kman I've already post a SC in the description